# Highlighting / Emphasizing Gmail-Addon

Tags: gmail-addons

I am building a Gmail Add-On via Google App Scripts that will display provide helpful actions for emails with certain content.

Is there a way for me to highlight / emphasize / flash the icon for my Add-On (on the right hand sidebar)? This would let me notify the user that the Add-On can provide some functionality for the email they're reading.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no such functionality provided by Google team. The only way an add-on is activated by only user action(user has to click on the add ons icon from right side bar).